# How to return from a function again and again in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. In the following method, I tried to print without returning. That's fine. What I need is I need to return as follows. (Need to read result with this while loop). I know once return we can't loop back. Problem is result should be returned in every iterations as soon as result is available. (similar to one thread read result once it is available while other thread is running this loop). Can I use callback to resolve it?

```
list<string>MyLogRetriever::handleEventsOnEventID(std::string logType, DWORD eventID)
    {
        while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) != true)
        {
            wstring wsLogType = stringToWidestring(logType);
            LPCWSTR lpcwstrLogType = wsLogType.c_str();

            string string_query = "";
            string_query = string_query + "*[System/EventID= " + to_string(eventID) + "]";
            wstring wsCons = stringToWidestring(string_query);
            LPCWSTR pwsQuery = wsCons.c_str();

            getEvents(lpcwstrLogType, pwsQuery, -1);
            //printResultedEvent(myLogStructures, numberOfAvailableEvents);
            return returnResultedEvent(myLogStructures, numberOfAvailableEvents);
            numberOfAvailableEvents = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to return one at a time, or can you get all of the results and return them all at once? The first option would be a lot easier if C++ had generators (like `yield` in Python and C#), which isn't happening officially for a while yet, although MSVC has initial support and Clang is working on it.

Comment: @chris I need to return one at a time. Result is not available at once..Can I use callback to resolve it?

Comment: You could, if the time-effort-maintenance balance is good enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is similar to a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29):

> In computer science, a generator is a special routine that can be used to control the iteration behaviour of a loop. In fact, all generators are iterators. A generator is very similar to a function that returns an array, in that a generator has parameters, can be called, and generates a sequence of values. However, instead of building an array containing all the values and returning them all at once, a generator yields the values one at a time, which requires less memory and allows the caller to get started processing the first few values immediately.

While this feature is widely known and supported in other language such as Python, there is no official support of generators in C++ yet.

As a workaround, you might want to use a table and pass it as an argument to your function and also append each result to it and return it each time instead - **you could write a class with a method `next()` to yield the next result** (*credits go to [Siyuan Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832878/siyuan-ren) for this*).

Comment: Or write a class with a method `next()` to yield the next result.

Comment: @naltipar I think next() is not suitable. Because I need result immediately once it is available. Please consider the last edit

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way to return from a method.  If you want to capture more information, you need to append to some sort of structure (eg. an array, or other couplex object), and return that instead.  In your case, you would declare it before your while loop is executed, and use that inside the loop.  Or you can call the method multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: I need to return one at a time. Result is not available at once..Can I use callback to resolve it?

Comment: @naltipar's answer is what you want then.  The idea is that you need to encapsulate the method in an object so that it can maintain state so that the next time next() is called, it will return the subsequent one.  If you don't encapsulate it in an object, you would have to use some variant of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Functions mathematically are  constructs that perform a calculation and return a result. Function generally refers to a binary relation, that has a 
unique mapping for every item in it's domain(set of inputs) to it's codomain(set of outputs).Now, those set elements could themselves be aggregate.

I am not an expert in other languages such as Java or Python, but I guess this holds true for them too.

As per your use case, you could return an aggregate(vector,map,set etc) from the function as output.

Comment: I need to return one at a time. Result is not available at once..Can I use callback to resolve it?